# Accessing JAX-WS webservice from .NET 4.0 client

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, jax-ws, webservice-client

What I trying to do is access to webservice written in JAX-WS java from .net 4.0 client.

When I'm trying to add reference to that webservice via https it's succesfully added to my project but then I'm unabled to build my project got errors like :

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Test.Test.ListDevicesResponseReturn.System.get'`

I tryed to change my client version to 3.5 but it's doesn't help.

I don't know how this webservice is written.

Thanks for any reply:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got answer ... It's a silly but in WebService written in JAX-WS was a property named `System` which is reserved in .NET Framework when I changed this Property name to `SystemJs` everything seems to working fine.

I hope it will help someone else as well.
Thanks all for trying help:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an object like this:

```
Test test = new Test();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's not this I'm do nothing only add service reference and trying to build.

Comment: Can you build before adding the service reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps here. I think you may have to manually generate the client from the command line.  [Developing a .NET Client](http://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Developing_a_Microsoft__NET_Client.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer but It doesn't help:(

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are calling a non static property from a static method. Someone of you method is not static.

**Hope these helps. :)**